# unit test a react component- jest, enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I am unit testing react component. One component imports other component and use its props. Here are jsx files :

```
class First extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        const { name, isSelected, onClick } = this.props;
        const activeClass = isSelected ? styles.active : '';
        return (
            <div
                className={`${styles.first} ${activeClass}`}
                role="button"
                tabIndex={0}
                onClick={() => onClick(name)}
            >
                {name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

First.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    isSelected: PropTypes.bool,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default First;
```

Here is my second class that imports this class :
i

```
mport First from '../First/First';

const Second = ({ values, passedVal, onClick }) => {
    const second = values.map(vlaue =>
        <First
            key={value}
            name={value}
            isSelected={value === passedVal}
            onClick={onClick}
        />,
    );

    return (
        <div >
            {Second}
        </div>
    );
};

Second.propTypes = {
    values: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    passedVal: PropTypes.string,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default FilterList;
```

Here is my test. I want to test isSelected condition in my test :

```
describe('Second - Unit test', () => {
    let props;
    let secondComponent;

    const second = () => {
        if (!secondComponent) {
            secondComponent = shallow(<Second {...props} />);
        }
        return secondComponent;
    };
      beforeEach(() => {
        props = Second.defaultProps;
        secondComponent = undefined;
    });

   it('verify value of isSelected ', () => {
             props.passedVal='value01';
             props.value=['value01'];
            console.log(props.isSelected);
           });
```

It gives me undefined as this is prop of First class. How can i verify this logic here. Need to make instance of first and then check?

Answer (score 1):

`props.isSelected` will be undefined, as you do not pass any value to it, and it does not have a default prop.

I think that instead of:

```
props.passedVal='value01';
props.value=['value01'];
```

You'll want to use:

```
secondComponent.setProps({
  passedVal: 'value01',
  values: ['value01']
});
```

Notice that in your test, the component is already mounted, and thus assigning new values to the props object will not actually affect the component. Using enzyme's `setProps` will though. You can read a bit more about that: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setProps.md

Furthermore, `isSelected` is a prop of the `First` component, so please notice that when you try to check its value in the test.

Comment: I tried above, it gives me error "can not read property 'setProps' of undefined".

Comment: Are you sure you call the `second` function which renders the component?

Comment: Yes, i am able to set property . I verified using console.log() . I am facing issue in testing isSelected prop. How can i call it? its prop of first class? can i not test it here? If i get correctly, when component is rendered isActive should be there. I tried using : const isActive= secondComponent.find('div');   expect(isActive).toEqual(true);  but it failed.

Comment: I recommend using enzyme's `mount` function in this case instead of the `shallow`, as it will also render the `First` component. Then, after you set the props, you can query the `First` component and check its props, something like: `secondComponent.find(First).prop('isSelected')`

Answer (score 1):

Wen using `shallow`the test is executed on component as a unit, and does not  indirectly asserting on behavior of child components. However you could check for a property of a child component using `find`, example (not tested):

```
const wrapper = shallow(<First/>);
expect(wrapper.find(Second).first().prop('isSelected')).to.equal('yourValue');
```